# Does Stack Overflow profile its users?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering how strict Stack Overflow is about privacy. Does it profile the people asking questions so it promotes only those it sees as worthy of getting points, perhaps for the profit of Stack Overflow or someone related to the site?

Comment: If you want to know about SE’s privacy “strictness”, you should probably [read its privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy). As far as reputation goes, though, Stack Exchange’s software certainly doesn’t attempt to influence how much you earn based on who it might think you are.

Comment: @false Except for Jon Skeet of course.. the reputation system can't help favour him, no matter how it was written. (note for the benefit of the OP: It's a joke).

Comment: The *userbase* of Stack Overflow sees and judges the content you offer, and many of those people of experts in their fields. They have high standards and will hold you to them.

Comment: I imagine only promoting the questions belonging to a small subgroup would not be a wise business decision, since it might hurt the overall popularity of the site. My experience is that if you ask a good question, it will get seen (and confusing ones tend to get just downvoted). Do you have a question in mind that you feel has not had the attention it deserves?

Answer (score 6):

To the best of my knowledge, Stack Overflow does not discriminate based on OpenID provider. For that matter, questions aren’t ranked on anything unrelated to the question yourself: if you have a history of terrible questions but somehow miraculously contribute a fantastic question, it will be presented as any other fantastic question, disregarding your history.

This follows from one of the tenets of Stack Overflow: it’s the content that matters, not the user.